# ES6 imports are not called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got problem with **this** code:

```
/* src/app.js */
import axios from 'axios'

export const run = async () => {
   console.log(axios)
}


/* test/app.js */
import {run} from ../src/app

describe('#run', () => {
    it('should work', function () {
        run()
    })
})
```

When I run the code I get **this error**:

```
ReferenceError: axios is not defined
```

I'm also using **Babel**, but I don't think it's relevant.

I really don't get why axios is not defined there. With old-style **require** syntax it works correctly, why it doesn't with ES6?

Code is run with **Node.js**.

Comment: Are you bundling with webpack/rollup/parcel? Or are you importing these files directly from the browser?

Comment: I'm running it with node.js. Sorry, forgot to include it in problem description.

Comment: Do you have dependencies installed ?

Comment: Yes, of course. There is a different error when module is not installed.

Comment: Which version of node are you using, how do you call it? Do you pass command line flags, do you use a transpiler? Is this the exact code you have (`import {run} from ../src/app` doesn't suggest so)?

Comment: Node version: 10.6.2 (current LTS)
I'm not using flags, but mocharc.json instead: "require": ["@babel/register", "core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"]
I guess no, not sure what it is.
Yes, it's exact code.